# fluid height in sticky footer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height, sticky-footer

I'm stying bootstrap sticky footer on my project: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/sticky-footer.html

Is it possible to set height of content to fill remained space? 
Let me explain. I want to reside image and I need to it gets sized relates to available height.

Comment: I don't understand you. Content already fills remaining space. If you want to add image in content to scale depending on content height and width, use `img {max-width: 100%; max-height: 100%;}`

Comment: But there is header yet.

Comment: @Eric So place header inside content, create another div for items or whatever and add image or background to that items div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is fill any space between the end of the content and the start of the footer, I can see all sorts of challenges.

Depending on the specifics of your image, maybe you can include it as a background like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/hBzjn/

You could use media queries, possibly with different images at different viewponts and also use padding to refine the results.

Good luck!

**HTML**

```
 <div id="wrap">
    <div class="contentWrap">

  <!-- Begin page content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Sticky footer</h1>
    </div>
    <p>page content</p>
  </div>

  <div id="push"></div>
    </div><!-- end contentWrap -->
</div> <!-- end wrap -->

<div id="footer">
  <div class="container">
      <h3>sticky footer </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap{
background: url(http://is.gd/0QPvoC) left bottom; /* define image and position */
}

.contentWrap{
background-color:#fff;  /* quick fix so background image is hidden behind main content */
}
```